# Working with designing student payment for each month and every year

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am currently doing the project requested by one of my friend (he will pay me though after finishing this project), but right now I am confuse on what have to do with the Student Payment on every year and every month.

I am considering to design the database like this:

[image: The Student Name change it to Student ID]

***Note: The Student Name will be changed to Student ID***

But, I am aware that I could not think enough on how to accomplish this.

Do you guys have any thought and/or any advices and/or any ideas on how to accomplish the Student Payment? Basically, what I want is make the database where inside it got Student ID and every Students ID have month payment (every month) until it goes to every year (probably until 2015)

Thank you so much! Your answer will be much appreciated!

***Update:***

I am considering also on make the database like this:

[image]

What do you guys think about this?

Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome!

***Another Question:
How to adding checkboxes to the database and whenever another StudentID has been added to the database, the checkbox for given months (January until December) is added also for that StudentID.***

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting all of this into the one table, why not split it up into two tables.

```
Student Table
Student ID | Student Name | Course | etc...

Payments Table
PaymentID  | Student ID   | Amount | Date | etc..
```

That way you can store each student's payment against the student id and the year.

**Example Usage**

You store each student, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Student(`Student Name`,`Course`) VALUES("Dave", "Astronomy");
```

Then you can update Dave's payments:

```
int id; // Assume you know the ID.

INSERT INTO Payment(`Student ID`, `Amount`, `Date`) VALUES(id, 500, "15-12-1992");
```